# Facets in Algolia Search Result depending upon the category

Tags: search, react-native, algolia

I am implementing `Algolia` Search in `react-native` , if i search a certain `keyword` i'm getting `response` from different categories like clothing, electronics etc. how can I get the facets list in the search result depending upon the categories in result.
like the
price will be common for all categories
Size will be there for fashion category only
Ram will be for electronics only

Comment: Hi dynamic faceting (what you are asking for) is not yet a feature of our libraries, it will be soon, do join the discourse forum to get updates on releases: https://discourse.algolia.com/c/announcements

Answer (score 1):

There is a [onSearchStateChange(nextSearchState)](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/widgets/InstantSearch.html) prop in <**InstantSearch**> component that is called every time a search is made and passed in the next search state (that contains active refinements). You can use this function to add a little bit logic to decide whether or not a refinement list should be rendered.

For example, inside this function you can maintain a hash table that contains visibility statuses for every refinement list. When rendering, you could add a condition to render or not a refinement list depending on the status in the hash table.